# Jenkins Snyk Task Not Finding Vulnerabilities Found via Snyk Web Scan

Tags: security, jenkins, snyk

Running Snyk from their web page against a Github repo, finds 7 High Severity issues in the pom.xml file.

I've configured Jenkins to run against the same project with the Snyk plug-in, but just get:

> Snyk installation is UP-TO-DATE Testing for known issues...
>
> > /var/lib/jenkins/tools/io.snyk.jenkins.tools.SnykInstallation/synk-tool/snyk-linux
> >     test --json --severity-threshold=low Result: 0 known issues | No known
> >     vulnerabilities Remember project for continuous monitoring...
> >     /var/lib/jenkins/tools/io.snyk.jenkins.tools.SnykInstallation/synk-tool/snyk-linux
> >     monitor --json --severity-threshold=low Archiving artifacts Build step
> >     'Invoke Snyk Security task' changed build result to SUCCESS

The Synk plug-in uses the token from the snyk.io page and is configured in Jenkins with all default values.

Comment: Can you share the project you are trying to monitor? Looking to replicate the issue on my side. Also, if you could edit your post with your config file (excluding sensitive data) that would help.

Comment: Is the project also showing 0 vulnerabilities once monitored on snyk?

Comment: @PStember Running the project through the snyk web scan shows 7 high severity vulnerabilities from scanning the pom.xml.

I cannot give you access to the project.

An example vulnerability (which we will fix) is that the pom.xml references version X of a particular dependency and that upgrading to a newer version will remediate it. 

We would like this to show in the Jenkins build, but the Snyk task in Jenkins reports "0 known issues | No known vulnerabilities".

Comment: @PStember What do you mean by "config file". Is this a Synk thing? We are using the Jenkins plug-in out-of-the-box.

Comment: In that case, it should be fine. what could also be an option is that you have a policy file in your project. @Paul, I would suggest that if the issue persists, you get on a call with them to solve this and report here the reason afterwards.

Comment: Could you point to documentation on this policy file? I did not see reference to it on the Jenkins Snyk plug-in page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197863/discussion-between-pstember-and-paul-croarkin).

Comment: This question appears to have stalled for 2.5 years. Is this still an open issue for you, @PaulCroarkin ?

Answer (score 2):

Another reason could have been the differences between CLI scans and SCM scans in Snyk, due to some variables that are not supported or private dependencies for instance. That would be discovered in CLI but not SCM if you haven't integrated with Artifactory (but in this case the number of vulns in CLI would have been higher than SCM actually)

This is an article that explains it in details
https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-cli/test-for-vulnerabilities/differences-in-vulnerability-counts-across-environments

Note that since this question, Snyk has dramatically improved the SCM accuracy for Maven, and there should hardly be a difference between SCM and CLI results.